# Can “in its own right” be used to mean “in itself”?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I’d like to use the phrase “in its own right” to mean “in itself” as in:

> This subject has no practical application, but is interesting in its own right.

Is this a correct usage of the phrase? How is this understood by native speakers? Also, do you know of good alternatives?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+its+own+right

Comment: @MετάEd I already looked up the phrase in some dictionaries, but the entries don’t clarify the word usage to me in this case. I cannot tell from them whether this usage is correct or not. Also, I recall seeing this phrase used in “subject to be studied in its own right“.

Comment: Also, I read the help page, saying word-choice and word-usage questions are welcomed here. Doesn’t this classify as a word-choice or word-usage question? How is this question not appropriate?

Comment: Questions which can be answered by simply consulting a good reference book are off topic. But sometimes references don't tell the whole story. That's why we ask you to show your research results in the question text. Can you please edit your question to show your own research efforts and what you found inadequate about the results (why you need the advice of an expert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  “interesting in its own right” is a grammatically correct phrase, properly used, and likely to be understood by most native speakers.

Reasonable alternatives include adverbs based on any of the following:
• *[inherent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inherent#Adjective)*, “naturally as part or consequence of something”
• *[innate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/innate#Adjective)*, “Inborn; native; natural; as, innate vigor; innate eloquence”, etc.
• *[intrinsic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intrinsic#Adjective)*, “Innate, inherent, inseparable from the thing itself, essential”

For example:  “This is an impractical but intrinsically interesting subject.”