# An excellent novel in its own right

Tags: word-usage

What does   the following [sentence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+its+own+right) mean?

> An excellent novel in **its own right**.

---

Somebody can be rich in his/her rights but how can a book be excellent in its own right. At the end books are written by someone. I cannot understand how this, one's own right, is applied to **objects**. I don't ask what " one's own right" mean in general.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116519/can-in-its-own-right-be-used-to-mean-in-itself

Comment: @Matsmath I had seen this thread before I asked the question but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Does this help ? ***In  its own right***: 

:  because of its own special qualities and not because of a connection with something else   - *Though it's based on a best-selling novel, the movie is great in its own right.* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20its%20own%20right

Comment: If you are asking "Where does this idiom come from?", then you should show us your research, and clarify why do you need an expert's attention.

Comment: It is an idiom (meaning that the meaning of its parts does not mean what the whole does). I've never really understood what it's supposed to mean beyond "it stands by itself" or "not only is it good in _comparison_ to similar ones, but would be good without all those to compare against".

Comment: @Josh61 your example made me think that my sentence needs another sentence which explains why it is excellent its own right to make sense as whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does mean exactly what it says. By contrast, here are some descriptions of novels that might not be excellent in their own right:

- It is an excellent novel for understanding the seventeenth century.
- It is an excellent novel for a beginning author
- It is an excellent novel for reading at the beach
- it is an excellent novel because it became such a great movie

They are excellent for some purpose, or with some qualification, or for some reason other than its own quality.

Comment: As you can see I got the sentence from a dictionary and after I read your answer I think there needs another sentence actually which explains why the book is excellent to make sense better..

Answer (score 2):

"In its own right" is an idiom meaning, roughly, "based on its own merits".  You are right that it seems a little nonsensical in the quoted usage, but it means that the novel itself is excellent, and does not depend on, say, the reputation of the author to give it merit.